# Gerrit http authentication on Debian System

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm searching for a suitable solution of my problem since a couple of hours.

I installed Gerrit and tried to set my auth type to HTTP. Thus, I had to adjust a http conf file similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerAdmin felix@localhost
 ServerName www.gerrit.test

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyVia Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

  ErrorLog /var/log/gerrit.log
  CustomLog /var/log/gerrit.log combined

  <location /login/>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
     Require valid-user
     AuthUserFile  /etc/httpd/passwd/gerritpass
  </location>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=SM_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}]
</VirtualHost>
```

But I really don't know in what way my this Server is started, since there isn't any new configuration file in my /etc/apache2/conf.d folder.

Do you now where to find a set of clear instructions how to make this type of authentication possible?

Thank a lot!

Comment: the virtual host configuration sections go to a separate so-called "site" files, located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. They are being enabled using `a2ensite` command, which actually creates a symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Place this configuration there. Anyway use the correct port number (:80) for the virt host: here you are setting `<VirtualHost *:8080>` which collides with your reverse proxy settings.